# OpenGL: Memory (texture storage) gets corrupted when running lots of applications

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm building an OpenGL based application. It uses some high-res textures. Sometimes, when switching to other applications running on my computer, and coming back, the memory of some of my texture storages gets corrupted . I am not 100% sure of what is happening, but it feels like the driver is short on memory so it steals some blocks of memory of the texture storage of my application and gives it to other applications. Once I come back to my application, there are black rectangular holes in some of my textures.

I can totally understand that the system runs out of VRAM and things like this happen, but I would like to be informed about this when this happens, so when the user returns to the application, I can restore memory buffers if they got invalidated.

Is this behaviour normal, or is the driver supposed  to sort of swap out texture data and restore it later (and is not doing that or failing to do so)? If this behaviour is normal, how do I detect that this happened and how do I deal with this?

For the sake of completeness: I'm experiencing this on macOS Sierra on a MacBook Pro 8,1 which has an Intel HD Graphics 3000 and 16 GB of ram.

Comment: That's not normal.

Comment: You cannot detect stuff like this (on OS X), but by the same token it's not supposed to happen if the driver is functional. Versions of OpenGL newer than OS X supports have robustness extensions that will notify you when a context is reset so you can decide to reload resources as necessary. Any implementation that does not support those notifications is in no position to pull the rug out from underneath your feet and should be expected to handle swapping resources in/out of VRAM transparently as needed to handle context resets.